# How to make VBA function "VBA only" and disable it as UDF

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007, user-defined-functions

I'm writing a VBA function which I want to be publically available in other VBA modules within the same document, however I don't want it to be available as a UDF (User defined function).

If I use the public access modifier however my function is also be available as a UDF-formula that can be called from the cells within the workbook. I don't want this.

Is there an access modifier or other way that can help me obtain this "VBA only" behaviour?

Kind regards

Comment: Can you go into more detail into what this function does? This may help suggest ways of using VBA classes which are VBA only, and cannot be initialized from the worksheet. At least show the expected input arguments as output values.

Comment: Check the type name of application.caller within the function.  Have not tested this, but I think it should allow to to check whether a function is being called from a cell.

Answer (score 10):

If you use `Option Private Module` in the module in which the function appears, the function can be declared as `Public` and used in any of your other modules within your VBA project, but won't be accessible by other applications or projects, including Excel itself.

Answer (score 5):

This will return a #VALUE error if used in Excel.

```
Function VBAOnly() As Variant

    If TypeName(Application.Caller) <> "Range" Then
        VBAOnly = 1 'or some other return value
    Else
        VBAOnly = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: `xlErrName` would be better :)

Comment: Thanks, but I had hoped a mechanism would exist that made the function invisible to the spreadsheet. This way the function still is visible (e.g. in the autoComplete), it just returns an error. This is not 100% what I had in mind.

Comment: +1 on Dick's suggestion. @Skifozoa as per KFleschner's comment make this a `Private Function`

Comment: I don't know any way to make it completely invisible to the UI, but still accessible from other modules.  I don't know a ton about XLLs but they may offer that flexibility - probably more work than it's worth.  As a last ditch effort, you could show us the function and maybe someone can think of something clever.

Answer (score 2):

There's a little bit of confusion among answers, so here's a more encompassing explanation:

*Technically...* all functions in the standard VBA Modules can be called if the exact formula is entered. Even Formulas in `Private Functions` within `Private Modules`

Example

```
Option Private Module
Private Function hiddenEverythingExample() As String
    hiddenEverythingExample= "NOPE!!!"
End Function
```

Will still return a value if a cell has `=hiddenEverythingExample()`

[image]

However, I believe the objective of the OP was to **avoid having the itellisense populate these functions in the Excel Formula bar.**

The most frequent way I accomplish this is create a specific Module for all VBA-Only functions and put `Option Private Module` in the module definition (area above the functions).

[image]

This ensures all functions in this module will NOT appear in itellisense, but still be accessible to other modules along with itellisense.

Defining as`Private Function` also accomplishes this, but then the function is scoped exclusively to that Module, which may or may not be the requirement.

Note that YowE3K infers that a function must be both `Private Function` **AND** `Option Private Module`, but only one **OR** the other is necessary to eliminate the itellisense.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing a `Function`, write a `Sub`, and set the return via a `ByRef` argument. This way your function will be invisible to Excel (except via Alt F8, or Developer tab > Macros) and won't appear in Excel's intellisense.

Instead of

```
Function Add(Num1 As Double, Num2 As Double)
    Add = Num1 + Num2
End Function
```

use

```
Sub AddInvisible(ByRef Result As Double, Num1 As Double, Num2 As Double)
    Result = Num1 + Num2
End Sub
```

Note

1. That `ByRef` is not strictly necessary (since arguments are by default by reference in VBA) but it serves as a useful reminder that `Result` carries the return value.
2. You will need to make the necessary changes to your code, for example:

   `z = Add(x,y)`

would become

`AddInvisible z,x,y`

as demonstrated below:

```
Sub DemoAddInvisible()

    Dim Num1 As Double
    Dim Num2 As Double
    Dim Result As Double 'Result initialises to 0

    Num1 = 1
    Num2 = 2
    AddInvisible Result, Num1, Num2

    MsgBox Result ' See that Result has become 3

End Sub
```

A downside of all this is that the new code is somewhat harder to understand.

Comment: @phillp Swannell How would you call the AddInVisible macro without having `Result` defined? Perhaps show a full example?

Comment: @PGSystemTester I've amended my answer to show an example.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying. That's a clever idea. However, I think it sort of loses the "feel" of a function where you have a mechanism that you simply put something in... and get a result. Yours requires ensuring the same variable is scoped correctly. You would also neeed to reset the `Result` to be zero on every run. ANyway... cool idea. I gave you an upvote even though I would never actually use this 

Answer (score -1):

pass a parameter that only allows the function to run if a "magic* value is given to it.

Example - This will give the error `#NAME!` unless you know what the *key* is:

```
Function VBAOnly(key As Long)

If key <> 12345 Then
    VBAOnly = CVErr(xlErrName)
    Exit Function
End If

VBAOnly = True

End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

Using the `Private` modifier should only allow the execution in the module the function exists in.

Comment: Not so. Cursory testing shows that `Private` functions are accessible from Excel.